# FileNotFoundError WinError 3

Tags: python, windows-7, rename

I'm trying to learn how to edit files, but I'm a bit of a python novice, and not all that bright, so when I get a FileNotFoundError I can't figure out how to fix it despite several searches on the interwebz.

```
import os

old = 'Users\My Name\Pictures\2013\182904_10201130467645938_341581100_n'
new = 'Users\My Name\Pictures\2013\Death_Valley_1'

os.rename(old, new)
```

Comment: Is this the file your want to rename `182904_10201130467645938_341581100_n` ??..Does is exist?..

Comment: Yes, that is the file I want to rename, and does, in fact, exist.

Comment: It has no extension?..like ".txt" or something similar?

Comment: it does, It's a .jpg. Do I need to include that? If so would it be: Users\My Name\Pictures\2013\182904_10201130467645938_341581100_n.jpg ?

Comment: Of course. The extension is part of the file name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`'Users\My Name\Pictures\2013\182904_10201130467645938_341581100_n'` is a relative path.

Unless you are running your code from the directory that contains the `Users` dir (which if you are using Windows would most probably be the root `C:` dir), Python isn't going to find that file.

You also have to make sure to include the file extension if it has any.

There are few ways to solve this, the easiest one will be to use the absolute paths in your code, ie `'C:\Users\My Name\Pictures\2013\182904_10201130467645938_341581100_n.jpg'`.

You will also want to use `r` before the paths, so you want need to escape every `\` character.

```
import os

old = r'C:\Users\My Name\Pictures\2013\182904_10201130467645938_341581100_n.jpg'
new = r'C:\Users\My Name\Pictures\2013\Death_Valley_1.jpg'

os.rename(old, new)
```

This of course assumes your drive letter is `C`.

Comment: Thanks that helped, though it only changed my WinError 3 into a WinError 2 error putting the .jpg at the end of the file name fixed that.